# Estimating variance from sequence of random variable

Tags: estimation, multivariate-analysis, random-variable, convergence

Given $X\sim N(0,\Omega)$. Suppose that we can construct a sequence $\{X_n\}$ based on the observation such that $\{X_n\}\to X$ in distribution. My problem is to estimate $\Omega$ consistently using this sequence.

If $\operatorname{var} X_n$ converges to a "finite" matrix, then of course $\operatorname{var}X_n$ is the estimator that we want using the dominated convergence theorem. But, as we know $\operatorname{var} X_n$ can go to infinity, so in this case, what should I do? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: If $\text{Var}(X_n) \to \infty$, what would $\Omega$ be?

Comment: Thanks @jbowman for your comment. Let me explain what the problem is:
$X\sim N(0,\Omega)$ is given. And we can construct a sequence $X_n$ based on observation such that $X_n\to X$. The main problem is to estimate $\Omega$.

Comment: I understand that; the point is that if $\text{Var}(X_n) \to \infty$, then it seems plausible (you decide) that $\Omega = \infty$, writing very loosely, and that says something about the dist'n of $X$.  Also, in what sense does $\{X_n\} \to X$?

Comment: Do you have any theoretical information about the asymptotic distribution of $X_n$, specifically about its asymptotic variance? If you can further establish that the estimator is unbiased with respect to the true variance, in this case, you could estimate the sample variance conditional on the sample size T. Then you know it may not be an accurate estimator given a small sample size, but unbiasedness assures that if you repeated the sample collection enough times, on average you would estimate the true value of the variance.

Comment: @jbowman: the convergence is in distribution. I've added in my question. Thanks for your correction

Comment: Thanks @Majte. We don't know about the mean and variance of $X_n$, but we know the mean and variance of $X$ (the limit distribution of $X_n$) and what I am doing is in the large sample setting.

Comment: That's what I meant actually, sorry. Can you establish if it's unbiased? Then it would seem logical to my limited understanding that you can use it by plugging in the sample size into T into the limit variance. You are even then more lucky if you can draw many experiments from the population and thus getting a more accurate estimator over time. That's an educated guess..

Comment: Sorry @Majte, I don't understand about your explanation. Could you please explain this more detail? By the way, what is T and what do you estimator that I should establish to be unbiased?

Comment: T is the sample size, also denoted as N. I may be wrong. But the way I see it, you have $\Omega$ which is finite but some expression of the variance of $X_n$ which can be infinite. You want to estimate $\Omega$ is that right? If $\Omega$ is unbiased and you have an expression for it dependent on the sample matrix X and the sample size, you plug in the sample size into this estimator and you are done. However, since I don't have any information about $\Omega$ and what estimator you use, everything here is speculation.

Comment: @Majte: Yes, I have $\Omega$ which is finite and I can construct $X_n$ depends on the observation namely by $Y_1,\dot,Y_n$ such that $\{X_n\}\to X$. We know that $var X_n$ can go to infinity, this is my problem.
By the way, what do you mean with $\Omega$ is unbiased? What I know is the unbiasedness in the estimator. Thanks

Comment: I meant the unbiasedness in the estimator. However, I am sorry, I am just not getting the whole question. Can you rephrase your question and write down what exactly $\Omega$ is and what squence $X_n$ is? I guess then you may have more response here. As it stands it is a bit speculative as you say you haved $\Omega$ but then again you want to "estimate" it. You should have some theoretical estimator in place, no?

Comment: Thanks @Majte for your suggestion. I have rewritten my question [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/86669/estimating-fisher-information-matrix-given-estimator)

Comment: looks good and I can see now more complex than I previously thought. But some people here are really experts, so I hope you get an answer soon!

Comment: I hope so. :D.
By the way, thanks for your time @Majte